# Write a query to get top rep. users who have silver badges, but no gold ones

Tags: support, reputation, badges, data-explorer

I am trying to compose a query that will list all high rep users who have a silver badge, but no gold ones.

I am new to the SEDE. I have gone through the tutorial and properties documentation, but I cannot figure out how to use them to find out badges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1268247) does that for you.

I've first created a Common Table Expression and named it `Gold` to give me a set with all the users that have a Gold Badge (The Class = 1 depicts that).

Then I select from the users table and do a LEFT OUTER JOIN with `Gold`, joining on the userid. The Users that don't have a Gold badge will not have a corresponding row in Gold. That is the criteria we can use to filter the result set on, where Gold.id is null will select those rows that don't have a matching row in the Gold set.

```
;with gold as
(
  select id
       , userid
  from badges
  where class = 1 -- Gold
)

select users.id as [User Link]
     , reputation
     , creationdate
     , lastaccessdate
     , views
     , upvotes
     , downvotes
from users 
left outer join gold on gold.userid = users.id
where gold.id is null
order by reputation desc
```

When run today this is the result:

[image: result set showing user Doug Currie with 37639 rep, Neville Kuyt with 25667 rep and 13 more rows of users]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the magnificent [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).